# Azure Functions pre-compiled c# using System.Data.SqlClient missing reference

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I created a Timer `Azure` Function that called an API and wrote that `json` response to `Azure` SQL DB.

I wanted to continue my project, so I created an `Azure` Functions App in `VS2017`.  I moved my code over and changed the #r script reference to the precompiled reference for the sqlclient.

From: (script calls)

```
r System.Configuration

r System.Data"

TO: (pre-compiled calls)

using System.Configuration;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Now I'm receiving a missing assembly reference for "System.Data.SqlClient" and I'm not sure how to add it to my Azure Functions App project in VS.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to your `csproj` to check which framework you are targeting. Based on your error, I guess it looks like this:

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

Which means you are on .NET Standard / Functions V2.

Either change it to .NET Framework / Functions V1:

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
```

or reference the .NET Standard version of `System.Data.SqlClient`:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.4.3" />
```

V1 is the production version for now, and it's the one used for C# script, so I suggest you stick to it.